# Can we have a page in SXA site without Theme

Tags: sxa

Is there a possibility to have page in SXA without any default styling (which is coming from SXA Theme)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, to do that you would simply change the layout on the pages presentation details from the SXA `MVC Layout` to a custom layout, then you would control all your CSS etc.. in there.

[image]